# Cygwin git not picking up aliases

Tags: git, cygwin, msysgit

I'm using Cygwin and the git (v1.7.9) that came with it by default (/usr/bin/git). I also have msysgit (v1.7.11.msysgit.0) installed. In my .bashrc, I do

`export GIT_CONFIG=path_to_.gitconfig`

and when I run `git config --list`, I get the contents of my `.gitconfig` (relevant excerpt below):

```
 ...
 alias.co=checkout
 alias.br=branch
 alias.ci=commit
 alias.st=status
 alias.logp=log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"
 alias.logl=log --pretty=oneline
 alias.graph=log --pretty=format:"%h - %an : %s" --graph
 ...
```

however, if I run `git ci -m "this is a test"` I get

```
 git: 'ci' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

 Did you mean one of these?
    am
    citool
    commit
    config
    diff
    fsck
    gc
    init
    mv
    rm
```

Does the git that comes with cygwin have to be set up differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured, that git will try writing to the .gitconfig file it was loading when aliasing a new command so I ran `git config --global alias.testalias random_git_command`. Then from my home directory

```
 grepc -R testalias ./
```

I was able to determine that it was using `~/.gitconfig`. So the solution was to make a symlink `ln -s [path_to_desired_.gitconfig] .gitconfig` in my home directory.

Still finding weird that when I ran `git config --list` I could see the list of aliases, but when I tried running them, git would not recognize them as a valid alias...

Comment: It could be that running `git config --global --list` would have shown them.  This looks in your ~/.gitconfig, not local to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by including the git aliases with the [alias](http://www.linfo.org/alias.html) command in the `.bash_profile`:

```
alias gch='git checkout'
alias br='git branch'
alias ci='git commit'
alias gs='git status'
alias gcd='git checkout develop'
alias gcm='git checkout master'
alias gph='git push'
alias gpl='git pull'
alias unstage='git reset HEAD --'
alias ga='git add -u .'
```